# record user session id on table after insertion in yii (Cannot use a scalar value as an array)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

i just realize ,that i can't insert the current user session that logged in after doing create on the table i am prefer to,

i cook the codes on the _form.php like this , then that warning appear (Cannot use a scalar value as an array)

```
 $use_id=Yii::app()->user->id;$use_id=intval($use_id);
         echo $form->hiddenField($model,'operator_id',$use_id); ?>
         <?php echo $form->error($model,'operator_id'); ?>
```

i have tried to not using 'intval' , but it appears the same, please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the session value in your controller function. you need not specified in form page or any other view pages.

example :
In controller->create function

before your `save()`

```
$model->operator_id =  Yii::app()->user->id;
```

i think its best way to assign values without using `hidden fields`

Comment: can i push it on the create function ??

Comment: yes you can.(`Note: after assign the attribute values, you can assign the session values.`)

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation of CActiveForm

```
public string hiddenField(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

You need to change these

```
$use_id=Yii::app()->user->id;$use_id=intval($use_id);
echo $form->hiddenField($model,'operator_id',$use_id);

//to 
$use_id=Yii::app()->user->id;
echo $form->hiddenField($model,'operator_id',array('value'=> $use_id));//
```

Comment: yes , i have copy paste that code, working on mine too, but i realize i shouldn't use hidden field, because it's readable on the 'view page source'